# How to load a locked screen in html when i press shift+l keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a index.html form, a login.html form and a lockedscreen.html form. When i press the Shift+L buttons, when i'm in the index.html it should load into the locked screen with a transition effect fade out. I tried using JQuery but didnt work . Please help

Comment: what you have tried so for? show you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').keypress(function(e){
       if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode===76){
          window.open('lockedscreen.html');
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try above code

Comment: well if possible can you show how to load it the page itself, just like refreshing

Comment: `window.open(url, '_self')` will open url in the same window. Try this.